# I want to use a cell as an input box

Tags: excel

I want to use only one cell to fill in a table in excel. The way I want it to be is first we take a set of conditions and a cell which I am going to put data in every time. If a specific condition meets upon each entering into the box then that value sits right into one of the table's empty cells. So every time a condition happens to be true it takes the value in the entering cell and saves it into one of the empty places in the table. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel macro and handle Worksheet_Change event. Be sure to ignore the changes that happen outside your cell, as any change to the event will trigger the event

Naz